# how to remove negative values from object using javascript or es6

Tags: javascript, algorithm, object, data-structures, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to check if an object has items with negative values using `javascript` or `ES6`, if that is the case remove it from the object?

```
foo = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1}
```

**result** should be the one below

```
foo = { 0: 0, 1: 2}
```

Sorry, i am coming from a `python` background but i would love to hear from you.

Comment: Do you want to *mutate* the object or create a new one?

Comment: @trincot yes! i am fine with that.

Comment: It was an or-question...? You mean "yes mutate" or "yes new"?

Comment: From the looks of it (not keeping the key value paring and keys always being consecutive numbers that start at `0`). You should probably use an array.

Comment: @trincot my bad. `create a new one` would be fine

Comment: @titus the data that i am dealing is currently in that format.

Answer (score 4):

You could filter the values and get a new object.

**Assumptions:**

- Object contains only index like keys (32 bit positive integer values).
- Keys starts from *zero* to *n*.
- The order should remain constant.
- The new object has now keys from *zero* to *m* where *`m <= n`*, depending of the count of the positive values.

The solution takes the values of the object in the standard order of ECMA-262 ([Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38218582/1447675)), filter this array and assigns the array to an object.

The result is an object with key and values from the filtered array.

```js
const
    data = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1 },
    result = Object.assign({}, Object.values(data).filter(v => v >= 0));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what should be the output if we provide input something like `data = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: 4 }`?

Comment: @Nithish, this: `{ 0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4 }`

Comment: Yes I checked that, is it intended output in that case? shouldn't it be `{ 0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3:4 }`

Comment: afaik, op would takes keys from 0 ... n and values in order without negative values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter` to remove elements with negative values:

```js
foo = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1}
let positives = Object.entries(foo).filter(e => e[1]>=0);
foo = {};
positives.forEach(([key, value], index) => {
     foo[index] = value;
});
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify the existing object rather than make a copy, you can do this:

```js
let foo = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1}
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(foo)) {
    if (typeof value === "number" && value < 0) {
        delete foo[key];
    }
}
console.log(foo);
```

Note: I added the `typeof value === "number"` as a type-safety check so you make sure you're comparing a numeric value in case there are other types of properties.

---

Or, in a reusable function that can be used with a user-supplied condition:

```js
// callback passed (key, value) and
//   return true to keep, false to remove the property
// function returns original object with desired properties removed
function filterProperties(obj, callback) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (callback(key, value) === false) {
            delete obj[key];
        }
    }
    return obj;
}

let foo = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1}
filterProperties(foo, (key, value) => !(typeof value === "number" && value < 0));
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Added a reusable function version.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new object

```
const fooWithoutNegativeValues = Object.entries(foo).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => value >= 0 ? {...acc, [key]: value} : acc)
```

To mutate its not different

Answer (score 1):

```js
const foo = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1}
const result = Object.keys(foo).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(foo[curr] >= 0) {
        acc[curr] = foo[curr]
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: FYI, this makes a new object.  It does not remove properties from the existing object.  It also only checks to see if the value is not `-1` rather than check if it's negative.

Comment: Mutating the object is against the functional programing rules and might have unintended consequences, but same logic can be use to mutate the `foo`, I updated the answer to check the negative values.

Comment: Objects are mutated ALL the time.  Have you never assigned a property to an object?  It depends entirely upon what the programming situation calls for.  The OP asked "to remove negative values from the object".  They didn't ask to make a copy of the object with different properties.

Answer (score 0):

This code will only modify the object to delete negatives.

```
foo = { 0: 0, 1: -1, 2: 2, 3: -1}

Object.keys(foo).map((key) => {
    if(foo[key]<0){
        delete foo[key]
    }
})

console.log(foo);
```

For a short explanation, Object.keys(foo) will turn the object into an array based on the key names. Then .map() loops through each key in the array, and if the condition passes, it will delete the variable.